# How do i prevent my route from refreshing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So i have a php function which is connected to a route. Whenever a button in the site is clicked this triggers the function that i have and refreshes the page. However im trying not to refresh the page when the button is clicked. Any ideas how i could do this?

This is the code below of the function, so far im aware that im refreshing the page my returning redirect. What can i change here to make the page not refresh?

```
public function quickbooking(Request $request, $place_id){
 // Getting information from the row
  $startDate = $request->startDate;
  $startDate = date('Y-m-d');
  $endDate = $request->endDate;
  $endDate = date('Y-m-d');

  $place_id = $request->place_id;

  $place = Place::where('place_id',$place_id)->first();
  $place->place_id = $request->place_id;
  $place->user_checkin = $request->startDate;
  $place->user_checkout = $request->endDate;


  // Saving the data
  $booking = new Booking();
  $booking->place_id = $place->place_id = $request->place_id;
  $booking->user_checkin = $startDate;
  $booking->user_checkout = $endDate;
  $booking->save();

  return redirect()->route('admin.place.viewplaces');
}
```

Comment: You can't do this just with PHP. You need to use Javascript. You can start researching about `Ajax` requsts.

Comment: Please share your button click function and what you want to save your data